# downloading of file using XHRHttpRequest not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, download, xmlhttprequest

I am doing an XHR request to an API to retrieve the raw data for a file.

This request then returns the file data a blob, I create an object URL from said blob and create a href element where I can set the file name and the download attribute then i programmatically click the link and it downloads the file.

However this is only working in chrome and not firefox.

here is the code used to make the request and download the file on a successful request.

```
onDownload: function(e) {
            if(e) { e.preventDefault(); }

            // removes the document store location from the base URL to match the endpoint for downloading a document
            var url = this.baseUrl.replace(/\/(?!.*\/).*/, "");
            var downloadUrl = url+ '?publicUrl=' + this.model.get('location');
            var self = this;

            var xhr =  new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', downloadUrl, true);
            xhr.responseType = 'blob';

            xhr.onload = function(xhrEvent) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    self.fileIsAvailable(xhr.response);
                } else {
                    self.fileIsNotAvailable(xhr.status);
                }
            };

            xhr.send();
        },

        fileIsAvailable: function (response) {
            Analytics.sendEvent({
                category: Analytics.categories.documentPicker,
                action: 'download-success'
            });    

            // create file and download link, then clicks download link to download file
            var blob = response;
            var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
            downloadLink.href = downloadUrl;
            downloadLink.download = this.getFileName(this.model.get('location'));
            downloadLink.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl);

            // window.open(downloadUrl, '_blank');
        },
```

My understanding is that firefox does not support the .click() function, as the request is going through and I can see a successful response with the file in firebug, it just doesn't download.

To try and get it to work on FF I amended the download functionality to this:

```
fileIsAvailable: function (response) {
            Analytics.sendEvent({
                category: Analytics.categories.documentPicker,
                action: 'download-success'
            });    

            // create file and download link, then clicks download link to download file
            var blob = response;
            var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            window.open(downloadUrl, '_blank');
        },
```

which again worked in chrome (although i cant set the filename on download with this) but still doesn't work in FF.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you're better off having a link for the user to right-click and "Save as...".  What you're doing is forcing a download which is why the `click()` function is not working in FF (I'm surprised it works in Chrome, tbh).  This isn't something to "work round", but rather "work with".  Just add a download link to the page when the file is ready.

Comment: I see what you mean, the issue is that to get to this stage the user does click a download link. click that link runs the `onDownload` function which sends the request to the api to retrieve the file, it doesn't get a link to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone wondering I have FF downloading a file now by adding these two lines to the download function:

```
document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

            setTimeout(function() {
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl);
            }, 100);
```

so my download function now looks like:

```
fileIsAvailable: function (response) {
            Analytics.sendEvent({
                category: Analytics.categories.documentPicker,
                action: 'download-success'
            });    

            // create file and download link, then clicks download link to download file
            var blob = response;
            var downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
            downloadLink.href = downloadUrl;
            downloadLink.download = this.getFileName(this.model.get('location'));
            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
            downloadLink.click();
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl);
            }, 100);

        },
```